# normalize or not?

Tags: foreign-keys, normalization, hierarchy

I have a DB in which there are 4 tables.

A -> B -> C -> D

Current the way I have it is, the Primary Key of A is a foreign key in B. And B would have it's own Primary Key, which is a foreign key in C, etc etc.

However, C can't be linked to A without B.

The problem is, a core function of my program involve pulling matching entries from A and D.

Should I include the primary key of A in D too

Doing so will create unnecessary data duplication 'coz A->B->C->D are hierarchy.
see pic for what D would look like.[image: Proposed Table D]

Comment: This doesn't look like a normalization issue to me. (Not yet, anyway.) This looks more like a surrogate key (id number) issue. Post the actual structure and sample data for all four tables as DDL and INSERT statements for the best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take all D-s in relation with given A, I would keep it normalized.

But if you want specific subset of such D-s and its easy to know which in advance, but time consuming later (eg. if you want all D-s from newest C from newest B), I would prefare storing this shortcut somewhere.

It does not have to be in D itself (esp. if you don't want all D-s connected with A).

If you want to do it to make your queries easier to read and write, then consider view.

If you want to do it to increase performance, try everything and measure it. (And I'm not expert in performance tuning of SQL, so I have no specific advice beyond that)

Comment: if I don't store it in D. and store it in a table specialized for A-D relationship. However, A and D are actually connected through B and C. Wouldn't that be a risk for double data(relationship), and not all updated at same time

Comment: It definitely would. Therefore it should be as automated as possible. Something like materialized view, trigger, or if you update A,B,C,D programaticaly (and never manualy), then it can be in that programatical update (inside same transaction). Its tradeoff. I would realy hard try not to use it, but I wish I used it in one specific project where we had tree data in SQL tables and we actualy needed only newest leaf of newest branch of newest branch of root and reads were much more frequent than writes.

Comment: Thank you!  you comment is most helpful